# Sendgrid Python reply_to email

Tags: python, class, email, sendgrid, reply

I have errors when I use reply_to, here is what I've tried...

This works but without reply_to :

```
mail = Mail(
    from_email = from_email,
    to_emails = to_email,
    subject = subject,
    html_content = content)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

And I've tried this :

```
mail = Mail(
    reply_to = reply,
    from_email = from_email,
    to_emails = to_email,
    subject = subject,
    html_content = content)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

This thows :

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reply_to'

I have also tried to add this after Mail() :

```
mail.from_EmailMessage(reply_to=ReplyTo(Email(email=ANS_EMAIL,name='Mr X')))
```

Which throws :

> TypeError: object of type 'Email' has no len()

And :

```
mail.reply_to(ReplyTo(email=ANS_EMAIL,name='Mr X'))
```

Which throws :

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Any help please ?

Comment: Which version of Sendgrid python package are you using?

Comment: Thx, I'm using 6.2.0

Comment: Issue is you're using mail.reply_to like a function but it's a setter so use it like a property (as mentioned in answer below)
ie mail.reply_to = xxx vs mail.reply_to(xxx)

Answer (score 4):

As your error states `reply_to` is not accepted in `init()`. Try setting `reply_to` after you have created the Mail object.

Example Below:

```py
mail.reply_to = "reply-to@website.com"

or 

message.reply_to = ReplyTo('reply-to@website.com', 'Reply Here')
```

More details on how to customize sendgrid email object - [Link](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/use_cases/kitchen_sink.md)

Comment: mail.reply_to = "reply-to@website.com" worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I managed doing this :

```
data = {
    "personalizations": [
     {
      "send_at": date,
      "subject": objet,
      "to": [{"email": to_email}],
     }
 ],
 "from": {"email": FROM_EMAIL, "name": "..."},
 "reply_to": {"email": "...@...", "name": "..."},
 "send_at": date,
 "subject": objet,
 "content": [
     {
      "type": "text/html",
      "value": body
     }
  ]
}
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=data)
```